# installing easy-rsa examples onto a Raspberry pi-3

Tags: pi-3

I have installed openvpn on my Raspberrypi-3 and am trying to add the easy-rsa examples to the installation. After inputting the following command line:

```
cp -r /usr/share/doc/openvpn//examples/easy-rsa/2.0 /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
```

I get the following response :

```
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/doc/examples/easy-rsa/2.0': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The tutorial is from 2015 are you sure you're working with the same versions ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Raspbian Jessie, you'll have to do this :

```
cp -R /usr/share/easy-rsa/* /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
```

Instead of this :

```
cp -R /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0/* /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
```

Full Documentation Here : https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN

Comment: Hi HG Sur.   Thanks for the suggested command line input.  After entering the command, the response is twenty lines of output each stating: cp: cannot stat. '/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/build-ca Permission denied.   This for build-ca, build-dh, build-inter, build-key, build-key-pass, build-key-pkcs12, build-let-server, build-request, build-req, build-req-pass, clean-all, inherit-inter, list-curl, openssl-0.9.6.cnf, openssl-0.9.8.cnf, openssl-1.0.0.cnf, pkitool, revoke-full, sign-req, vars, whichopensslcnf.

Comment: All of the above were denied permission.

Comment: Having browsed the answers on this list I discovered the following command line input:   sudo apt-get install easy-rsa.  The output was: sudo: unable to resolve host rasberrypirogersrasberrypi-3 followed by:  reading package list....... Done, Building dependency tree, Reading state information .....Done, easy-rsa is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.      I then entered : sudo make-cadir /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa.    Response was:  sudo unable to resolve host rasberrypirogerradberrypi-3 followed by: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa exists.  Aborting.

Comment: This is followed by:

Comment: An explanation that it creates a new directory for holding keys and certificates which is self explanatory

Comment: It is not clearly whether easy-rsa is actually installed.  Perhaps someone can confirm it is so.

Comment: @magnanimousrogera If you are getting permission denied as the `pi` user, use `sudo`.  Around here it is commonplace to include that in an example, but more widely if you are reading information about linux it is not, because understanding **permissions** is assumed to be a very basic and fundamental thing ;)  Just beware sudo doesn't work if the command involves redirection (has `>` to a file node/stream).  But these do not.

Comment: Actually, I had entered : sudo: -s which should have made it unnecessary to enter sudo before the command line input.  However, I have now entered the command that HGSur suggested with the sudo command before it and I now get the following output: sudo: unable to resolve host rasberrypirogersrasberrypi-3.  This is followed by: cp: '/usr/share/easy-rsa/build-ca' and '' /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/build-ca' are the same file.   This is the same for -dh, build-inter, build-key, build-key-pass, build-key-pkcs12, build-key-server, build-req, build-req-pass, clean-all, inherit-inter - more to follow.

Comment: list-crl, pkitool, revoke-full, sign-req, and whichopensslcnf.      I have already advised previously that, although I have used Macs for many years, I am completely new to Linux and Rasberry and thus struggling to get the pi-3 set up the way that I want it.   I am very grateful for all the advice I have received on this web site.